# gcc: how to not compile with warnings

Tags: gcc

I would like to know if there is any gcc flag that doesn't compile to an object file, if there are warnings in the respective source file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`gcc -Werror`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html): Make all warnings into errors.